# Como implementar el algoritmo KNN o vecino mas cercano en java?

Tags: java

No logro encontrar un ejemplo practico de este algoritmo en java, lo mejor que he encontrado ha sido la libreria weka, sin embargo no logro entender como aplicarla a mi caso, este es el link que estaba estudiando pero nisiquiera puedo entender como funciona la formula de la distancia presentada aqui

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-weka3/index.html

[image: knn]

```
Distance = SQRT( ((58 - Age)/(69-35))^2) + ((51000 - Income)/(150000-38000))^2 )
```

De esta formula no logro entender de donde sale el /(69-35) ni el /(150000-38000) si alguien me puede aclarar esto podria continuar e intentar implementar el knn por mi cuenta, o si alguien me puede dar un buen ejemplo de KNN también se agradece.. quedo atento a sugerencias o inquietudes.

> EDICION:

Yo hice una investigacion extensa pero sin frutos hasta el momento, porque no entiendo realmente lo que estoy haciendo, tratare de explicar de donde obtuve todo, mi codigo ya esta comentado

Primero investigando esto fue lo mejorcito que encontre:

Este primer link me dice como sacar el knn supuestamente:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554796/how-to-get-the-nearest-neighbor-in-weka-using-java

Y este link me dice como crear las intancias (cosas que aun no comprendo que son para weka)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118132/adding-a-new-instance-in-weka

Y con esos dos links arme este codigo el cual pueden ejecutar:

```
public class Wekatest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Attribute> atts = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> classVal = new ArrayList<>();
        // Nose lo que estoy haciendo aqui, porque se hace esto (esto lo hacen en el segundo link)
        classVal.add("A");
        classVal.add("B");
        classVal.add("C");
        classVal.add("D");
        classVal.add("E");
        classVal.add("F");

        atts.add(new Attribute("content", (ArrayList<String>) null));
        atts.add(new Attribute("@@class@@", classVal));

        // Aqui en mi caso mis datos a evaluar son platos por eso le pongo TestInstancesPlatos
        Instances dataRaw = new Instances("TestInstancesPlatos", atts, 0);

        // Yo me imagine que cada instancia es como un objeto que sera comparado luego con las demas instancias
        // Para ver cuales son los vecinos mas cercanos...
        double[] instanceValue1 = new double[dataRaw.numAttributes()];

        instanceValue1[0] = dataRaw.attribute(0).addStringValue("Pizzas");
        instanceValue1[1] = 0;

        dataRaw.add(new DenseInstance(1.0, instanceValue1));

        double[] instanceValue2 = new double[dataRaw.numAttributes()];

        instanceValue2[0] = dataRaw.attribute(0).addStringValue("Tunas");
        instanceValue2[1] = 1;

        dataRaw.add(new DenseInstance(1.0, instanceValue2));

        double[] instanceValue3 = new double[dataRaw.numAttributes()];

        instanceValue3[0] = dataRaw.attribute(0).addStringValue("Pizzas");
        instanceValue3[1] = 2;

        dataRaw.add(new DenseInstance(1.0, instanceValue3));

        double[] instanceValue4 = new double[dataRaw.numAttributes()];

        instanceValue4[0] = dataRaw.attribute(0).addStringValue("Hamburguers");
        instanceValue4[1] = 3;

        dataRaw.add(new DenseInstance(1.0, instanceValue4));

        double[] instanceValue5 = new double[dataRaw.numAttributes()];

        instanceValue5[0] = dataRaw.attribute(0).addStringValue("Pizzas");
        instanceValue5[1] = 4;

        dataRaw.add(new DenseInstance(1.0, instanceValue5));

        System.out.println("---------------------");

        weka.core.neighboursearch.LinearNNSearch knn = new LinearNNSearch(dataRaw);
        try {

            // Este metodo recibe la instancia objetivo de la que quieres conocer los vecinos mas cercanos
            // Y N (nose que es N, yo supongo que cuantos vecinos quiero.. en el primer link mencionan esto) respectivamente.
            Instances nearestInstances = knn.kNearestNeighbours(dataRaw.get(0), 1);
            // Yo esperaba que el output fuera el vecino mas cercano a la instancia objetivo pero
            // La verdad no logro interpretar el output


            System.out.println(nearestInstances);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Dependencia de weka:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka</groupId>
        <artifactId>weka-stable</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Output obtenido:

```
---------------------
@relation TestInstancesPlatos

@attribute content string
@attribute @@class@@ {A,B,C,D,E,F}

@data
Pizzas,A
Tunas,B
Pizzas,C
Hamburguers,D
```

Lo que yo esperaba:

Que me dijera que el vecino mas cercano de la instancia objetivo (0) que es Pizzas A, fuera el Pizzas C, pero pues no lo se la verdad espero que alguien me pueda ayudar con esto.

Comment: Agrega el código que hayas intentado por favor, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: @Jorgesys Listo amigo, no se si sirva de mucho pero he agregado tambien dos referencias de donde obtuve el código (mas importante es la segunda), sin embargo no lo comprendo.. por eso estaba pensando mas bien entender el algoritmo y hacerlo por mi mismo pero si alguien me explica mucho mejor

Comment: No se si ya ha avanzado en lo de la formula, pero la formula es una formula de distancia normalita `(a²+b²)^(1/2), en cuanto a los valores el 58 lo toma porque es la edad que desean saber que producto puede comprar, los de `69-35` es por que es el valor más alto menos el menor, los otros valores son los relacionados a las edades pero de la columna `income`.

Comment: @isaac hey muchas gracias por tu aporte, la verdad sigo en este mismo punto porque estoy avanzando en otros aspectos del proyecto que contiene esto, pero oye con respecto a lo de la formula, podrias aclararme unas dudas? primero en la formula la variable A quien es? y la variable B quien es? y ese 69-35 me dices que es el mayor menos el menor, osea siempre para cada set de datos que tenga aplicaria esa misma regla? mayor dato que tengo menos el menor, te agradezco mucho que hayas pasado ayudar por aqui :)

Comment: @isaac osea te pregunto eso porque si es asi siempre voy a usar esta formula (a²+b²)^(1/2) que me has dado solo necesito saber quien sera a y quien sera b y listo podria programar el algoritmo yo mismo jeje a mi manera claro porque no me queda mucho tiempo

Comment: No se que dice el ejercicio, pero por lo que puedo deducir, y me corrige si estoy equivocado, lo que se desea saber es que artículo podria comprar una persona de 58 años con un capital de 51.000, lo de distancia hace referencia a cual de los anteriores clientes se asemeja más (esta más cerca), creo que en la formula de distancia las variables `Age` e `Income` se reemplazan por los pares correspondientes como (45 , 45000) donde 45 es la edad y 45000 el Income, esto dara un dato (puede que sea el score, no se), espero no confundirlo más, es lo que a mí parecer se ha de solucionar.

Comment: @Isaac no me has confundido, al contrario, gracias amigo.